# css sprites in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-sprites

I have created a sprite menu with 5 levels. 1st level contains "HOME" and etc., along with "SIGNUP" and "LOGIN". 2nd level is when the 1st level is hovered. 3rd level is when active. 4th level is similar however it has "My ACCOUNT" & "LOGOUT" instead and the 5th level is just hovered of "My ACCOUNT" & "LOGOUT". How would I tell wordpress to use the 4rd if the user is logged in and 5th level if they click/hover over "My Account" & "Logout". I'm using the latest release of Wordpress.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea in the first place? Seeing as the browser won't be able to extract text from the sprites, for search engine and accessibility purposes. Independently from that, I think you will need to show the actual image and some CSS/HTML to get some answers

Comment: Well, sprites save load time and space which is good for SEO however it won't be a good idea if I plan on adding more pages and etc in the future within WordPress because I would have to go back and edit the sprite. Other than that I think it is.. but since you brought this up, I actually don't know because with css3 I can create exactly what I did in Photoshop but then that means I wasted my time with photoshop :/ Also I plan on adding divs that display dynamic data within and around the div that holds the sprite so would this sprite still be a good idea? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the sprite as the menu/buttons background, and give the various levels different css classes.

So for the 5th level you can use the :hover class. For the 4th level you can use wordpress's if user is logged in function to give things different classes -so something like

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
<div class="my-button class-5"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="my-button class-4"></div>
<?php }; ?>
```

where 'class-4' has the background set to your 4th level sprite and 'class-5' has the background set to your 5th level sprite.

Comment: Thanks. I would put this php code inside the header.php of my theme right?

Comment: @jay Hi- not really no - you would put it actually in your template where you want the instance of the button to occur. Wordpress is full of really useful conditional tags that you can use anywhere in your template - its worth reading up on them here http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags.

Comment: @jay don't forget to start your answers with @jorgeluis if you want me to know you're done it

Comment: Thanks Jorge. While reading the link you provided above, I just realized something.. I've created a sprite menu that basically consists of pages or categories that I've made in wordpress. So that would mean I have to go back and create the drop-down menu sprite as well.. I'm starting to think I've created more work for myself and this isn't the best solution for a custom wordpress menu ._. Thanks again though!

Comment: @jay yep - you'd have to hand code the menu for what I've suggested to work. there's not a lot of flexibility in custom menus I'm afraid. you could always hand code just that line of the list and let the custom menu do the rest.... I'f you're happy with my answer don't forget to select the tick!

Answer (score 1):

Working with CSS sprites in a menu with each item being an image of its own ("Home", "About....") is a very bad idea.

- It's poison for accessibility
- It may be harmful for SEO
- It's a lot of work to maintain the sprite images
- Menu items won't scale when the user uses their browser's "zoom" function
- Users with images turned off have no way of seeing what the menu item says

It's hard to give an alternative suggestion without seeing the intended design, but the most common way is probably to build a `<ul>` based navigation (each item being a `<li>`) and giving each element a background image. Depending on your situation, you may be able to work with CSS sprites there to show the hovered and unhovered states.

Comment: Yep, I just realized it and took the time to learn the power of the new wp menu editor. Question has been answered! :D